# Is readdir_r atomic?

Tags: multithreading, atomic, readdir

I'm planning to create a function that relies on [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) function with mutexes added for better multithreading handling (because the function can return a shared static variable that can be modified by different calls to the function).

Although, the manual page tells points a reentrant variant named readdir_r. Does this variant assure atomicity for calls from different threads ?

Comment: Are the threads sharing a `DIR` instance? Or are they each operating on their own `DIR` returned from  `opendir`?

Comment: Atomicity is a big word.  readdir_r just fixes the multi-threading bug, you get to pass your own buffer.  Don't use a global variable ;)

Comment: @David Schwatz Each thread has its own DIR handle.

Comment: @Hans Passant The documentation states the fact that function readdir uses a global variable (just like localtime).